# applications of LMVT theorem

Tags: limits

If the tangent to the curve $f(x)=x^2$ at any point $(c,f(c))$ is parallel to the line joining $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ on the curve , then what is the relation between $a,c,b$ ?

ans: $a,c,b$ in AP

here which theorem we have to apply and how?

Answer (score 1):

Simple. $f'(c) = 2c = \dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \dfrac{b^2-a^2}{b-a} = b+a$. This means $a,c,b$ are in AP.